# Outlook AddIn mailsend

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I want to deploy an addin to outlook 2013.

The basic principle is that if an employee send an email to a certain adress, then the addin will auto fill his body with some info he must provide.

i tried this but it won't work.

```
 if (mailItem.To == "some@example.com")
                { 
                mailItem.Subject = "support ticket";
                mailItem.Body = "IP :[                       ]";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

When exactly does the code run? in the `Application.ItemSend` event? What exactly does not work? You need to be a lot more specific than that.

If it is (as I suspect) the test for the email address that is failing, you need to avoid using the To property and instead loop through the Recipients collection comparing each `Recipient.Address` property. If it is an Exchange mailbox, the address will be an EX type address (as opposed to SMTP) and you will need to use

```
`Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`
```

(be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions).